# How do I solve this CORS error when using TensorFlow.js to classify Cloudinary images?

Tags: vue.js, cloudinary, tensorflow.js

I am using the Vuetify Cloudinary Upload component to upload pictures to my Vue application. I then want to run the TensorFlow.js library on them to classify objects. Unfortunately, I get this error:

> DOMException: Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on
>   'WebGL2RenderingContext': The image element contains cross-origin
>   data, and may not be loaded.

Here is my relevant code:

```
import * as cocoSSD from '@tensorflow-models/coco-ssd';
let images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
let imagePromises = [];
for (let image of images)
    {
        image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
        imagePromises.push(this.model.detect(image)
            .then(classified => this.objects.push(classified))
            .catch(e => {console.log(e)})
        )}
await Promise.all(imagePromises);
```

Answer (score 1):

The image has to be served by a server which enables cross origin. Using the image directly from the file system will always throw the cors error issue.

Then the crossOrigin attribute of the image has to be set either directly on the html

```
<img src="url" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

or in the js script

```
image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous'); 
// or
image.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
```

Comment: As you can see above, I set the crossOrigin attribute to 'anonymous' before processing

Comment: I said in my answer that you have to serve the file over a server before setting the crossorigin attribute. I did not say that you didn't set the attribute, did I ? I only said that unless the image is being served by a server that allows cross origin, the error will always be thrown